# AspNet WebApi + Angular 7 Project Architecture

Tags: asp.net-core, onion-architecture

I am creating an asp .net core web api + angular 7 project from the scratch. After searching a lot, I couldn't find any document related to onion architecture to build the architecture design. Could someone provide any link to create the step-by-step architecture design document for reference..

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend this project for starting reference, https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular-universal

Comment: I expect something similar to this link, [link](https://www.toptal.com/angular/angular-5-asp-net-core). But the problem with that link is, as i run through the comments it says few files missing..

Answer (score 0):

To start, .net provides a template with visual studio (with core version) which can help you in setting up your initial project (unless you want to have independent angular project separate from the .net structure).

For onion architecture, I recently implemented the same and I found following link most useful.

[Onion Implementation](https://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/understanding-onion-architecture)